# Photoshop - Show same layer twice and edit both at the same time

Tags: adobe-photoshop

My title is very poorly phrased but I'm having a tricky time describing this.

Basically I am trying to create a repeating background right now. I would like to edit a certain area, but for Photoshop to show that same area next to the one I'm editing so I can see if there are seams.

I know some programs allow this (or allow it radially so you can create snowflake and kaleidoscope effects).

Is Photoshop able to do this?

Here is an image to try and illustrate better what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: If you are doing pixel graphics you can also look into using [Aseprite](https://www.aseprite.org/) which has a built-in mode for creating tiles. I'm praising it [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/132213/84899) 

Comment: @Wolff I think that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I'm not doing pixel graphics right now (making a parallax scrolling space background), but I'll keep keep that in mind if I do any pixel work. Thanks.