# GIMP: Disable Anti-Aliasing/Interpolation when Drawing

Tags: gimp, interpolation

Is there a setting that controls image interpolation when drawing? I want to create pixel art, and it is really annoying when the brushes paint the outher pixels of each stroke with some opacity.

Answer (score 3):

Use the ***Pencil Tool*** instead of the *Brush Tool*.

Comment: If you are into pixel art, have a look at [Aseprite](https://www.aseprite.org/). I praise it [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/132213). (I'm not affiliated with Aseprite. I just really like it. )